# Can atomic orbitals combine in a manner intermediate between bonding and antibonding?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

When atomic orbitals combine in phase (0°) we get bonding molecular orbitals, and when they combine with opposite phases (180°) we get antibonding molecular orbitals.

Why can't atomic orbitals combine in phases between 0 and 180?

Comment: You may combine orbitals whatever you like, but not all combinations make sense.

Comment: Take a look at https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Tutorials_(Rioux)/Chemical_Bonding/183:_Semi-empirical_Molecular_Orbital_Calculation_on_XeF2 where you get a bonding, a non-bonding and an anti-bonding orbital.